# What are the meanings of 心配の種になる and ゆとりを与える?

Tags: meaning

I have a problem understanding the meaning of the following sentence:

> 子供が心配の種になるのは事実であるが、ゆとりを与えてくれるかは不確実である。

weblio translates it to

> Children when they are little make parents fools.

But what are the meanings of `心配の種になる`and `ゆとりを与える`?
After some research and guess, here is my own translation:

> It is the fact that children always make us worry, but whether they give a think about /realize (understand) that or not is uncertain.

Can some one provide a translation that is more literal than what weblio gives?

Answer (score 4):

心配の種になる = become cause of worry

ゆとりを与えてくれる = give leeway/peace of mind

"It is certain that children will cause worry, but uncertain that they will give peace of mind." Seems like an overly literal Japanese translation of the phrase "Children are certain cares and uncertain comforts." The given translation was probably assigned in error.